# Regular expression to match unique words in files

Tags: regex, linux, perl, grep

To prefix unique words with "UNIQUE:" inside a file I've tried to use a perl regex command like:

```
perl -e 'undef $/;while($_=<>){s/^(((?!\b\3\b).)*)\b(\w+)\b(((?!\b\3\b).)*)$/\1UNIQUE:\3\4/gs;print $_;}' demo
```

On a *demo* file containing:

```
watermelon banana
apple pear pineapple orange mango
strawberry cherry
kiwi pineapple lemon cranberry watermelon
orange plum cherry
kiwi banana plum
mango cranberry apple
lemon
```

The output is:

```
watermelon banana
apple pear pineapple orange mango
strawberry cherry
kiwi pineapple lemon cranberry watermelon
orange plum cherry
kiwi banana plum
mango cranberry apple
UNIQUE:lemon
```

Unfortunately, the **\3** backreference doesn't seem to be handled if used in advance.

Is there another way to achieve this with another regex or with other usual commands available on a **Linux** box? (grep, sed, awk,...)

Many thanks

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately, many of the solutions works for the provided case only which was incomplete, my apologies for that, it should also work on a text like:

```
{watermelon || banana}
apple = ( pear pineapple orange mango )
strawberry cherry
kiwi = pineapple = lemon = cranberry = watermelon
orange - plum = cherry
kiwi = banana + plum
mango = cranberry && apple
lemon
```

If it simplifies the problem, words may be prefixed with something like $ or @.

Comment: Note that only "pear" and "strawberry" are unique in this demo file.

"undef $/" is used to read the file as a whole instead of line by line.
(((?!foo).)*) is normaly used to match anything which doesn't contain "foo".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see you are already using Perl. When you want to count something using a hash is always a nice approach...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = ();
my $str;

while(<>) {
    $str .= $_;
    $_ =~ s/\W+/ /g;
    map {$hash{$_}++} split ' ', $_;
}

for (keys %hash){
    my $word = $_;
    if($hash{$word}==1) {
        $str =~ s/\($word)/UNIQUE:$word/g;
    }
};

print "$str\n";
```

which will output:

```
{watermelon || banana}
apple = ( UNIQUE:pear pineapple orange mango )
UNIQUE:strawberry cherry
kiwi = pineapple = lemon = cranberry = watermelon
orange - plum = cherry
kiwi = banana + plum
mango = cranberry && apple
lemon
```

Using an regexp is probably going to be hard. You need to run through the entire file twice. One pass to count all occurrences of words and one pass to mark-up the unique words.

The above snippet read the input once, but keeps the entire original text in $str - obviously a bad idea if the input was large.

Comment: The replacement operation needs word boundaries. To see the problem, add another data item: 'berry'.

Comment: Nice catch, I added word boundaries in the regexp

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to do this with a single execution of a regexp. The reason for this is because after the first replace is done the internal cursor is moved at the end of that match, and the next time it starts matching it forgets what's behind it. And as it happens to be, dynamic look-behinds are not supported, so you can't check if "this word has already appeared before this matching position". What you can do, however, is replace one word with each execution of a regexp (because this way you can always anchor at the start of the string). So what you want to do is run the following regexp as long as it replaces something.

```
s/^.*?\K(?!UNIQUE:)\b(\w+)\b(?=(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*$)/UNIQUE:\1/s
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that you need boundaries on the replacement operation; otherwise a unique `apple` could collide with a non-unique `cranapple`, for example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);

my %words;
my $content = read_file(shift @ARGV);
$words{$_} ++ for split /[\s\W]+/, $content;
my @uniq = grep { $words{$_} == 1 and length } keys %words;
$content =~ s/\b$_\b/UNIQUE:$_/g for @uniq;
print $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why "lemon" is unique, but let's just say i assume it to be only a single occurence of the word, then here's an awk script

```
awk '{
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    words[$i]++
    if( words[$i] > 1){   delete words[$i]  }
 }
 a[++d]=$0
}END{
 for(i=1;i<=d;i++){
    m=split(a[i],t," ")
    for(k=1;k<=m;k++){
        if ( t[k] in words ) {
            t[k]="UNIQUE:"t[k]
        }
    }
    for(w=1;w<=d;w++){
        printf "%s ",t[w] 
    }
    print ""
 }
}' file
```

output

```
$ more file
watermelon banana
apple pear pineapple orange mango
strawberry cherry
kiwi pineapple lemon cranberry watermelon
orange plum cherry
kiwi banana plum
mango cranberry apple
lemon

$ ./shell.sh
watermelon banana
apple UNIQUE:pear pineapple orange mango
UNIQUE:strawberry cherry
kiwi pineapple lemon cranberry watermelon
orange plum cherry
kiwi banana plum
mango cranberry apple
lemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put every word on one line? If you can you can use the command *uniq*:

```
uniq -c yourfile
```

This way every unique word will have a count of 1.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I really have to mark unique words with something like "UNIQUE:" inside the original files.

Comment: uniq report or filter out repeated lines in a file, not words.